# How to sum a specific range excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and was wondering how I could code my macro to give me a "totals" row. I have already written a code to get it to display the word "totals" at the start of the line, but I am stuck on how to write a code to get it to display the sum of column B, C, and D in the totals row (row 11).

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the code you have? Also, use the Macro Recorder.  Turn it on, then do `=SUM(B2:B8)` in `B11`.  Then stop the recorder, view the code and you should have an idea as to how to add this via VBA.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("B11:D11").Formula = "=SUM(B2:B10)"`